# Cheat sheet exhibiting bash shell stdout/stderr redirection behavior

Tags: shell, stdout, pipe, stderr, tee

Is there a good cheat sheet demonstrating the many uses of BASH shell redirection?  I would love to give such a thing to my students.  Some examples I'd like to see covered:

```
cmd > output_file.txt       #redirect stdout to output_file.txt
cmd 2> output_file.txt      #redirect stderr to output_file.txt
cmd >& outpout_file.txt     #redirect both stderr and stdout to output_file.txt
cmd1      | cmd2            #pipe cmd1 stdout to cmd2's stdin
cmd1 2>&1 | cmd2            #pipe cmd1 stdout and stderr to cmd2's stdin
cmd1      | tee result.txt  #print cmd1's stdout to screen and also write to result.txt
cmd1 2>&1 | tee result.txt  #print stdout,stderr to screen while writing to result.txt
```

(or we could just make this a community wiki and enumerate such things here)

Thanks!

SetJmp

Comment: whats wrong with what you have there? just print it out! hehe.

Comment: Though not a cheat sheet, there is an [excellent discussion here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput).

Answer (score 2):

http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Bash-operators

Answer (score 2):

Peteris Krumins also has a pretty comprehensive cheat sheet: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-redirections-cheat-sheet/

Comment: Great reference!  I love the single-page cheat sheet.

Answer (score 1):

you can also look at [Advanced Bash Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)

Answer (score 0):

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html

Your students might appreciate a little bit of process substitution as well. It's very closely related to IO redirection.

Edit: It looks like Dennis Williamson's link already talks about process substition :)